# Efficient way to re-write this code?

Tags: python, performance

I have to measure  the time it takes with varying L values so I want to optimize my code. What I had to do is fill a cubic box (LxLxL) with periodic points (x,y,z) of diameter d that are identical. So far this is what i have:

```
L=10
d=2

x,y,z = 0,0,0
counter=0

with open("question1.xyz","w") as f:
    while x<=L-d:
        while y<=L-d:
            while z<=L-d:
                f.write('H ')
                f.write('%f ' %x )
                f.write('%f ' %y )
                f.write('%f\n' %z )
                counter=counter+1
                z=z+d
            z=0
            y=y+d
        z,y=0,0
        x=x+d
```

I then have to output the file (the .xyz file) that is in this format:

```
H 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 2.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 3.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 4.000000
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You could combine the write statements:
`f.write('H {} {} {}\n'.format(x,y,z))`

Comment: Also, consider writing a generator for the x, y, z tuples and iterating from it

Comment: You should go over your [questions](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1690243/john-jones?tab=questions) and [accept some answers](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work), so that people will answer your questions in the future.

Answer (score 3):

Several things can be done: first, separate data formatting from data generation, second, use [a cleaner iteration approach](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.product). In the first approximation that would be something like this:

```
from itertools import product

def iterate_3d(size, step=1):
    """ Generate the data using the standard lib """
    # an iterable range between 0 and `size` with `step`, not including size
    vals = xrange(0, size, step)  

    return product(vals, repeat=3)  # replaces your nested loops


def save(filename, data):    
    """ Format and save the data, which is a sequence of (x, y, z) tuples """
    with open(filename, "w") as f:
        for x, y, z in data:
            f.write("H %f %f %f\n" % (x, y, z))

def main():
    data = iterate_3d(10, 2)
    save("question1.xyz", data)


if __name__=='__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: hm, having trouble generating my file, what do you mean by:  """ Generate the data using the standard lib """
I am new to python (first week) so still trying to learn

Comment: That's just a docsting, it does nothing but comments the intention. I used the standard `product` function instead of the nested loop, that's it. What troubles do you have?

Comment: Thanks for the help
Nothing with the code specifically as in errors but the file is not generating. Sorry if its a noob question but the only way I learned to create files was through: with open("question1.xyz","w") as file: I tried running your code but it doesnt create an .xyz file

Comment: Ah, well, I've updated the code, so that the script can be run from the command line. `main()` or whatever you name it has to be called explicitly in Python.

Comment: thanks a lot for the help! I see what you did there and its really helped improve the running the program. - quick question, if I wanted to limit the number of particles (x,y,z) points, how would i implement that. The number is 526, should i throw in a while statement?

Comment: so something like, numpoints = 512 while numpoints<512.....

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/17502/discussion-between-bereal-and-john-jones)