# Ways to improve this code?

Tags: python

I have to measure the time it takes with varying L values so I want to optimize my code. What I had to do is fill a cubic box (LxLxL) with periodic points (x,y,z) of diameter d that are identical. So far this is what i have:

```
L=10
d=2

x,y,z = 0,0,0
counter=0

with open("question1.xyz","w") as f:
    while x<=L-d:
        while y<=L-d:
            while z<=L-d:
                f.write('H {} {} {}\n'.format(x,y,z))
                counter=counter+1
                z=z+d
            z=0
            y=y+d
        z,y=0,0
        x=x+d
```

I then have to output the file (the .xyz file) that is in this format:

```
H 0.000000 0.000000 0.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 1.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 2.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 3.000000
H 0.000000 0.000000 4.000000
```

Any ideas or suggestions? Thanks in advance!

Comment: mainly looking at ways to improve my iterations approach.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Efficient way to re-write this code?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12702784/efficient-way-to-re-write-this-code)

Comment: I think this question is probably better suited to [codereview.stackexchange.com](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

You should minimize the number of times you call `f.write()`. This minimizes the number of times the Python runtime must do system calls, which are typically costly.

So, build up a longer piece of the output, before calling the `write()` function. You can do this quite simply by adding to a string, or (even better) add to a *list*, and use `join()` when you're done to collapse the list into a single string, which you then `write()`.

Comment: Thanks - i rewrote it as: f.write('H {} {} {}\n'.format(x,y,z))

Answer (score 1):

```
from itertools import product

L=10
d=2

with open("question1.xyz","w") as f:
    f.write('\n'.join('H {} {} {}'.format(*t) for t in product(range(0, L, d), repeat=3)))
```

Comment: Are you missing a close bracket at the end? Also, I get a: IndexError: tuple index out of range error